# Convert $r^2-5r+6=0$ to a rectangular coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

The factor form of that expression is: $(x-2)(x+3)$ but I could be more simpler.

Thanks for a while.

Comment: Polar to rectangular --- do you know formulas for $r$ and $\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, but I can not identify an xy-axis specific surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: From $r^2-5r+6-0$ you get $(r-2)(r-3)=0$, and therefore $r=2$ or $r=3$.

- What are the equations in rectangular coordinates for $r=2$ and $r=3$? This is easy if you recognize what geometric shapes are involved.
- Suppose that you get equations $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ for the rectangular equations representing $r=2$ and $r=3$. What does the equation $f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)=0$ represent?

Comment: so there are two shapes.. thanks.

Comment: @Rakisbro: Yes. Remember that $ab=0$ iff $a=0$ or $b=0$, so you really can split $(r-2)(r-3)=0$ into two equations, $r=2$ **or** $r=3$.

Comment: It is important to recognize that condition. I appreciate your courtesy.